# What is the difference in estimation between A, B, and C? They seem very similar

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, statistics

This is a question in our econometrics class, and we're unsure of how to deal with the additional z2 and z3 in part B and part C.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions